# How to first insert one element to a list, then recursively insert all elements left

Tags: prolog

So I want to try to change the approach to my last question (because I don't really know how to phrase it). Let's suppose I want to add an element BEFORE I reverse a list

```
rev(L, R) :- rev(L, [], R).
rev([], R, R).
rev([H|T], C, R) :- rev(T, [H|C], R).
```

So before I call rev/3, I want to manually add an element (that I obtained from another operation, rule/4 for example. So I want that new list to first have the new element obtained from rule, and then the rest of the list, that I got by that 2nd element that acts as an accumulator. This is extremely simple in other languages but, how is it done in Prolog?

Added to that, if at all possible. How would I go about getting the LAST element, then adding it at the end?? Because so far, closest I got, would be to go element by element to the end of the list, get the element, then do something like:

```
add_tail([],X,[X]).
add_tail([H|T],X,[H|L]):-add_tail(T,X,L).
```

And in any other language I know this would be inneficient and kind of dumb. You go to the last element, get it, add it at the end. I do not find a way to do this in prolog without traveling the whole list a bunch of times.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you mean take the last element from one list, and add it to the end of a different list? If so, you could use `append/3`: `append(_, [LastElement], FirstList), append(SecondList, [LastElement], Result).` By the way, your `rev/2` implementation has termination issues since `rev(L, [a,b,c]).` will not terminate after finding a solution.

Comment: @WillBriggs if the OP is using reverse just to try to take the element from the end of one list and append it to another list, then `append/3` is a better solution than doing reverse at all.

Comment: That's not what I mean @lurker , I want to add an element I obtain from another rule, to the end of a list. That's why I used that example, because I will have to (if I understand it correctly) invert the list, then insert, then invert again (or some other similar approach). Didn't know rev/2 has problems, like, at all, I got that code from an answer here in SO

Comment: @keont thanks for the further clarification. But to my point, you don't need to reverse a list to add an element to the end of the list. You can use `append/3`. Not all answers here are issue-free, by the way. :)

Comment: Didn't know that at all. In fact I don't think I understand it very well but when I move from where I am I will try to see it by debugging, so thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add an element before reversing a list:

```
:- NewList = [NewElement|OldList], rev(NewList,NewReversedList).
```

Your `add_tail` function would be fine for adding an item to the end.  So would this:

```
:- reverse(ListIn,ReversedList),reverse([NewElement|ReversedList],Result).
```

This is twice as costly, but in O notation that doesn't matter.

You can't get away from lists having O(N) operations at times in PROLOG, except by not using lists (tis is actually possible if you have fixed length -- use functors) or by using smarter data structures (heaps, hash tables, etc.).  I wouldn't sweat it.  It's PROLOG.  Lists are how it does things.

Comment: so if I understand the code right, the first line adds an element to the left of the head (thus making it the head), then it reverses it, and the second reverses it, inserts, then reverses it again. Is that right?

Comment: In the first example, just, `rev([NewElement|OldList], NewList).` will do. You can unify within the call.